# Aggregating Columns Returns 'Column not iterable' Error

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to get percentiles for some columns in a spark dataframe, but the following code returns a "Column not iterable" error.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
        
exprs = {x: F.percentile_approx(x, 0.25) for x in df.columns}
        
df.agg(exprs).show()
```

Any suggestions as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg) if you supply a dictionary you need the key-value of the dictionary to be strings.
`F.percentile_approx(x, 0.25)` is not a string.

I recommend the following minor changes:

- make it a list instead of dictionary
- unpack it in the agg

see below:

```
exprs = [percentile_approx(x, 0.25).alias(f'{x}_25th_percentile') for x in
df.columns]
        
df.agg(*exprs).show()
```